# How to make tilt compensated magnetic heading using FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to build a multi-device magnetic compass app with `FireMonkey`.
How can I get tilt compensated Magnetic Heading ?

Answer (score 4):

On iOS, tilt compensated magnetic heading is available from the OS. TiOSLocationSensor (GPS) offers both MagneticHeading and TrueHeading in real time.

On Android MagneticHeading is NaN most of the time, or a value is available, but not in real time. So AFAIK it must be calculated from acelerometer + magnetometer readings.

Tilt compensation means the phone can be tilted (Pitch and or Roll <>0) without affecting the Heading (the Yaw angle). The accelerometer reading is used to rotate the magnetic vector. The default heading angle is in plane XZ (i.e. with the phone more or less in vertical position). If the phone is in landscape orientation, heading is in plane YZ and the axis must be rotated accordingly.

I got the formulas from
https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/design_tip/group0/56/9a/e4/04/4b/6c/44/ef/DM00269987/files/DM00269987.pdf/jcr:content/translations

```
// this function x,y,z axis for the phone in vertical orientation (portrait)
function calcTiltCompensatedMagneticHeading(const {acel}aGx,aGy,aGz,{mag} aMx,aMy,aMz:double ):double; //return heading in degrees
var Phi,Theta,cosPhi,sinPhi,Gz2,By2,Bz2,Bx3:Double;
begin
  Result := NaN;   //=invalid
  // https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/design_tip/group0/56/9a/e4/04/4b/6c/44/ef/DM00269987/files/DM00269987.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00269987.pdf
  Phi := ArcTan2(aGy,aGz);    //calc Roll (Phi)
  cosPhi := Cos(Phi);         //memoise phi trigs
  sinPhi := Sin(Phi);

  Gz2 := aGy*sinPhi+aGz*cosPhi;
  if (Gz2<>0) then
    begin
      Theta := Arctan(-aGx/Gz2);                 // Theta = Pitch
      By2 := aMz * sinPhi - aMy * cosPhi;
      Bz2 := aMy * sinPhi + aMz * cosPhi;
      Bx3 := aMx * Cos(Theta) + Bz2 * Sin(Theta);
      Result := ArcTan2(By2,Bx3)*180/Pi-90;      //convert to degrees and then add   90 for North based heading  (Psi)
    end;
end;

  //usage

  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  mx := MagSensor1.HeadingX;  //in mTeslas 
  my := MagSensor1.HeadingY;
  mz := MagSensor1.HeadingZ;

  aGx := MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationX;  //get acceleration sensor
  aGy := MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationY;
  aGz := MotionSensor1.Sensor.AccelerationZ;

  aMagHeading:=0;
  if IsLandscapeMode then  //landscape phone orientation
    begin
      aMagHeading := calcTiltCompensatedMagneticHeading({acel}aGy,-aGx,aGz,{mag} my,-mx,mz); //rotated 90 in z axis
    end
    else begin  //portrait orientation
      aMagHeading := calcTiltCompensatedMagneticHeading({acel}aGx,aGy,aGz,{mag} mx,my,mz);  // normal portrait orientation
    end;
  {$ENDIF ANDROID}
```

Comment: A cross platform sample of this can be found at 
https://github.com/omarreis/FiremonkeySensorFusion